# Django: count values with annotation from another table without ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have three models/tables:

```
class Stats:
    obj_type = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
    obj_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    views_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)

class Movie:
    title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    producer = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Cartoon:
    title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    producer = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

In total, I have around 1,500,000 objects in my Stats table. The *obj_type* field in it holds strings such as 'Movie' or 'Cartoon' related to the respective tables.

What I want to do is to get a list of all the *Movie* producers from the *Movie* table with the total count of views pertaining to every producer, e.g.:

```
Walt Disney: 17055    # total views of all Movies with 'Walt Disney' as producer counted based on Statistics table
Netflix: 15046
etc.
```

What is the most effective way to achieve this without having a ForeignKey? I.e. something like this if we had the views count inside the same table:

```
views = Movie.objects.values('producer').annotate(count=Sum('views_count'))
```

Comment: I am not seeing how `views_count` has any relationship to a given producer?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver An example: stat = Stats(obj_type='Movie', obj_id=77). Same as it would be with ForeignKey but I manually input the id and type of the related object. I cannot change the structure of the database due to space considerations, hence the question. So, for 5 Movie objects having the same producer, I can sum up the values of views_count from the 5 related Stats objects and thus get the aggregate amount of views related to this producer.

Comment: Where is the `obj_id` in `Movie`? If there is none then why even bother with `Movie`? Why not just do the `count()` on `Stats`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver obj_id in Movie is its pk (id), which is there by default. count() doesn't work on Stats because Stats doesn't have the producer column.

Comment: That would have been useful information to provide at the start. I am rusty on my Django skills but something like `from django.db.models import Sum Stats.objects.values('movie_producers', views=Sum('views_count'))`. For more information see [QuerySet Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/)